# C++ structures/arrays

Tags: c++

I'm creating a program that stores basic data. After inputing data for the first 'person', the program simultaneously loops to the second instance of `i` without accepting any input. This is hard to explain but I hope someone can help me out. I have a feeling that `getline` and `cin.ignore` are causing these problems. I only came across them on this website.

```
struct info {
     string name;
     string address;
     int phone;
};


int main(){
    int input;
    cout<<"How many people do you want on the list" <<endl;
    cin>>input;
    info arr[input];
    for(int i=0;i<input;i++){
        cout<<"Enter name for person " <<i+1 <<": ";
        getline(cin,arr[i].name);
        cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
        cout<<"Enter the address of " <<arr[i].name <<endl;
        getline(cin,arr[i].address);
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        cout<<"Enter phone number of " <<arr[i].name <<endl;
        cin>>arr[i].phone;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getline` consumes the newline but does not include it in the string, so you don't need to do `cin.ignore`.

Comment: [Why does `std::getline()` skip the input.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-the-input/21567292#21567292)

Comment: `arr[i].phone;` is meant to do what again please?

Comment: @user3286380 - Deleting cin.ignore messes up the program completely!

Comment: @0x499602D2 - Whoa! I just noticed that.That was a huge error! Thanks a lot. I'll edit it

Comment: Ok so replacing getline with a cin>>arr[i].name solves my problem. But now entering  a full name with spaces between first and last names doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @mRperFect `std::getline()` is still the solution in that situation. My answer shows you how to use it appropriately.

Comment: @0x499602D2 - Thanks, your help is immensely appreciated. I'm not(yet) familiar with vectors so understanding this might take a while. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: There's still the option of using C-style arrays, but you'd have to allocate them on the heap (meaning `info* arr = new info[input]`). That's the only way using a runtime variable as the size will work. Don't forget to deallocate that memory when you're finished using `delete[] arr;`.

Comment: @0x499602D2. Can you explain the following line:     std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, arr[i].name);

Comment: @mRperFect I'm guessing it's the `std::cin >> std::ws` that confuses you. `std::ws` is a manipulator like `std::endl` only its job is to discard leading whitespace from the input stream. The expression returns the stream again. It's exactly the same as `std::cin >> std::ws; std::getline(std::cin, arr[i].name)`.

Comment: @mRperFect Well it's not *exactly* the same. "Functionally equivalent" would be the proper term.

Comment: Could you also accept my answer below (click the checkmark)? :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Done! :) So what's the difference between cin>> and std::cin>> ? And how can I highlight my code?

Comment: @mRperFect The difference between `cin` and `std::cin` is that the latter is *fully-qualified*. `std::cin` and `cin` are the same object, but I like to write it as `std::cin` as it is more expressive about where it comes from (it comes from the namespace `std`). Moreover, using `cin` without `std::` is the common thing people do when they use `using namespace std`. [But it is generally looked down upon in the programming community](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) because names in the `std` namespace can clash with other names.

Comment: @mRperFect Also, you highlight your code by wrapping them with the character `\``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing formatted input with unformatted input is always asking for trouble. When you extract input into the stream, a newline is always appended. The newline character is the delimiter for `std::getline()`, meaning whilst extraction is being performed, if `std::getline()` finds a newline, it discards that character and stops input.

This is the problem you're running into. After the last formatted extraction `cin >> input`, the newline is left in the input stream. `std::getline()` (unlike formatted input functions) do not discard *leading* whitespace, so it is prone to the disadvantage I explained above.

To solve this issue, you need to discard leading whitespace manually, so the the non-whitespace input is ready to be extracted by the time `std::getline()` is invoked:

```
std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, arr[i].name);
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`std::ws` is manipulator which extracts and discards leading whitespace. This should be satisfactory for your purposes.

---

The following are suggestions that I advise you take. They lead to a substantially cleaner, clearer code structure. And it also reduces a lot of headaches:

> **1. Your class should have its own inserter/extractor.**

You should define your own inserter/extractor to encapsulate I/O semantics for your class. It facilitates a lot of the trouble of manual extraction. Inserters/extractors are typically implemented as `friend`s of the target class so that it may access private data members. Your class in particular has no private data members, but this is still an idiomatic technique nontheless:

```
struct info
{
    string name;
    string address;
    int phone;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const info&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&,       info&);
};
```

Inserters/extractors are *global* functions because they are being defined in terms of (not only) the target class, but also the stream object itself.

> **2. Use `std::vector<T>` rather than raw C-style arrays**

The following is wrong:

```
cin >> input;
info arr[input];
```

This code instantiates an array at compile-time with a size known only at runtime. The possibility of your compiler accepting this code fully depends on how standard-conformant it is. GCC has a non-standard extension which welcomes code like that, but it is non-standard even so and shouldn't be used.

If you need an array of objects whose size is known at runtime, use a *vector* of those objects. A vector class is already provided for you through the Standard library:

```
std::cin >> input;
std::vector<info> arr(input);
```

In fact, the size is superfluous since the vector will grow dynamically as more and more elements are created. You can simply default-construct the vector (unless you have a good reason to specify the size, in which case that many `info` objects will be default-constructed in the internal buffer of the vector).

```
std::vector<info> arr;
```

This is mostly it. Here is an example of your program that applies these two suggestions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct info
{
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    int phone;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const info&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&,       info&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const info& obj)
{
    return os << "Person's name is: " << obj.name << std::endl
              << obj.name << "'s address is: " << obj.address << std::endl
              << obj.name << "'s phone number is: " << obj.phone << std::endl;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, info& obj)
{
    std::cout << "Enter name for person " << ": ";
    std::getline(is >> std::ws, obj.name);

    std::cout << "Enter the address of " << obj.name << std::endl;
    std::getline(is >> std::ws, obj.address);

    std::cout << "Enter phone number of " << obj.name << std::endl;
    std::cin >> obj.phone;
    std::cout << endl;

    return is;
}

int main()
{
    int input;
    std::cout << "How many people do you want on the list" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> input; // just as a formality, but really the user can enter
                       // as much as they want.
                       // The value of input will be ignored.

    std::vector<info> arr;
    info obj;

    while (std::cin >> obj)
    {
        arr.push_back(obj);
    }

    for (const auto& item : arr)
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
}
```

If you have any questions, please leave them as a comment and I will try to help you as best as possible.